# Accessing local database (like SQL) for React-Native

Tags: react-native

How do you access a local database while using React-Native app? Especially if you're using a common JS that builds on both Android and IoS.

Or if you can't, what are the other ways? And are there guides for it?

P.S. I built my app using CRNA.

Comment: If you are dealing with small amounts of data in your app, then you can use AsyncStorage, look into:  http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-2

This is a simple and easy way to implement local database- SQLite